# How to change color of background for area under curve using andengine

Tags: box2d, andengine

I am using andengine and the box2d extension.  I am generating some hills using line bodies         that are generated based on a sinusoidal equation shown below.

```
public ArrayList<Line> CreateSinusoidalHills(PhysicsWorld world, int length, float density, float elasticity,
                                    float friction, int resolution, Engine engine, Scene scene)
{
    // resolution argument is how far the line is drawn for every iteration
    ArrayList<Line> lineList = new ArrayList<Line>();

    float xIndex = 0;
    float offset = 150; //TODO: add offset to function arguments
    for (int x=0;x<length;x++)

    {

        Line line = new Line(xIndex,(float)Math.cos(xIndex)*100+offset,xIndex+resolution,
                (float)Math.cos(xIndex+50)*100+offset,10.0f,engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        line.setColor(new Color(200,90,254));
        lineList.add(line);
        xIndex = xIndex + resolution;

    }
    return lineList;
}
```

I want to have the area below this generated curve be a different color than the background of the scene, but I can't figure out how to make that happen. I tried creating rectangles below each of the lines, but I lost a lot of performance (as I expected).  I thought perhaps I could use these x,y points to create a polygon that is the exact shape of the hills (at which point I could change its color) but I have not been able to figure out how to do that either (I can create the polygon, I just don't know how to add it to the scene because it doesn't seem to work the same way as a rectangle).  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

This is my first post so let me know if I am not following the proper protocol for asking a question. Thanks!